# Tensorflow.js, Transfer Learning to retrain based on a folder of images

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, p5.js

I am trying to retrain the MobileNet model using tensorflow.js and ml5.js. I am starting with one item ( drone images ). I have a folder with 88 drone images w. filenames 1-88.jpg all in the folder "droneTrainData". My project is based on the example in the ml5 website that uses the computers webcam to train and classify images. Here are the links for those. 
 ( https://ml5js.org/docs/custom-classifier and 
https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/tree/master/Courses/beginner_ml5/04_feature_extractor_classification )

I got this to work successfully but have been getting no where slowly trying to implement this with a folder of .jpg images.

I am getting the errors
1. pixels passed to tf.fromPixels() can not be null @ tf-core.esm.js:17
2.  Cannot read property 'width' of undefined @ p5..min.js:9

I have tried dozens of implementations so solve this but since I do not understand the fundamental root of my problem my efforts would most likely be useless to provide. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. I am starting at square one. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>  
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.13.1/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.1.3/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <script>

        let mobilenet;
        let featureExtractor;
        let classifier;
        let loss;
        let myImg;
        let imgArr = new Array();

        function modelReady(){
            console.log("model ready!")
        }


        function whileTraining(loss) {
            if (loss == null) {
                console.log('Training Complete');
                classifier.classify(gotResults);
            } else {
                console.log(loss);
            }
        }

        function gotResults(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                label = result;
                classifier.classify(gotResults);
            }
        }

        async function preload() {

            for(let b=0; b<88; b++){
                myImg = loadImage("droneTrainData/"+(b+1)+".jpg");

                imgArr.push(myImg)
            }
        }

        async function setup() {
            createCanvas(320,240);
            mobilenet = ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady);
            classifier = mobilenet.classification();

            for(let i=0; i<88; i++){

                await classifier.addImage(imgArr[i], "drone");

            }
            classifier.train()
        }


        let drawCount = 1
        height = 240
        label = "drone"
        function draw() {
              background(0);
              image(imgArr[drawCount], 10, 10, 320, 240);
              fill(255);
              textSize(16);
              text(label, 10, height - 10);
              drawCount++;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I figured this out. I'll either post the solution or delete this comment if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

P5.draw() is structure function, looping endlessly. You are increasing variable drawcount value (endlessly) and also trying to access imgArray element with index drawcount.

whether reinitialize drawCount or stop looping:

```
    function draw() {
          background(0);
          image(imgArr[drawCount], 10, 10, 320, 240);
          fill(255);
          textSize(16);
          text(label, 10, height - 10);
          drawCount++;
          if(drawCount == imgArr.length){
            noLoop();
            console.log('--- looping stopped ---');
            // or
            // drawCount = 1;
          }
    }
```